# Stretching buttons in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

In libgdx, you can create a TextButtonStyle that has images for up and down states, but when you set the size of a button it stretches the image. Is there anyway to make a button style that allows you to set the corners, sides and middle of a button so that instead of stretching the button image, it just tiles the sides and middle images? For example, a button in java's swing library can be set to any size without having a stretched look, but in libgdx a button stretches its image to fit the rectangle. This is more noticable on rounded buttons. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `NinePatch`. Basically that is an special kind of image that defines *strechable* and *not-strechable* parts of the image. A typical use case for the NinePatch is a Button as you usually don't want the edges to get stretched and just stretch the rest.

A Simple example of instantiating would be:

```
 NinePatch patch = new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("knob.png")), 12, 12, 12, 12);
```

For more details about this example you can see the wiki page about **NinePatches**: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches

Comment: Or simply he can create .9 png file and load it as regular texture. I think it might work, too.